# Extract a given set of files to a repository

Tags: git, git-filter-branch, git-filter-repo

I intend to extract a handful of files from a repository with ~10000 commits and 5000 files into a separate repository. Those files are spread across several directories, and there are unrelated files in those directories.

`git filter-branch`'s `--subdirectory-filter` is not really an option, since it only accepts a single directory. Also, it doesn't follow renames, so part of the history, if the file was initially introduced in another directory, is lost.

My current solution is:

```
git filter-branch --tree-filter 'fd -E 3166 -X rm -rf'
```

Where [`fd` is a faster `find`](https://github.com/sharkdp/fd), and `3166` is a unique part of the file name of all extracted files. What it does it goes through all the commits, find all unrelated files and removes them. This is horribly slow, however, it takes hours.

Is there a better approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you could test `filter-repo` (which is being recommended by git upstream to use instead of filter-branch). There you could specify more than one folder.... I guess you could provide all the directories that you care, both "current" and as you had them historically.

https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo

Comment: `git filter-repo --force --path-glob '*3166*'` just for the reference.

Comment: A word of precaution - if something goes wrong, `reflog` won't help, everything is rewritten from scratch.

Comment: Ok... that's a interesting comment. _old_ reflog gets dumped? :-O

Comment: Yep. Along with all the branches.

Answer (score 2):

`git filter-branch` also has an [`--index-filter` mode](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch#Documentation/git-filter-branch.txt---index-filterltcommandgt).

As the documentation states :

> This is the filter for rewriting the index. It is similar to the tree filter but does not check out the tree, which makes it much faster.

As the documentation still states : you porbably want to use it together with `git rm --cached [all the files that don't match your filter]`

Comment: Nice! `git filter-branch --index-filter 'fd -E 3166 -X git rm -r --cached --ignore-unmatch' HEAD ` is roughly 10 times as fast.

Comment: Actually should be `git filter-branch --index-filter 'fd -E 3166 | xargs rm -r --cached --ignore-unmatch' HEAD ` to avoid `Problem while executing command: Argument list too long`.

Comment: Except that it does not affect anything.

Comment: It works fine with a given set of files, but `fd`/`find` are helpful in this situation, and `git ls-files` should be used instead.
Trying `git filter-branch --prune-empty --index-filter "git ls-files -- ':!:*3166*' | xargs git rm -f"` now, but nested single misbehave, and the whole thing becomes quite complicated.

Comment: You can use a dedicated script to apply your actions

Comment: `git filter-branch -f --index-filter 'git diff --cached --name-only | grep -v 3166 | xargs git rm -rf --cached --ignore-unmatch'` didn't work either on a big repo, even though it worked with a smaller one. Another culprit that it swallows `Please tell me who you are ... no email was given and auto-detection is disabled` error.

Comment: I hoped `index-filter` would give a quick way to answer your need, it obviously doesn't. Have you tried to look at `filter-repo` as suggested by @eftshift0 ? When looking at the doc, this tool allows you to extract the history of some files matching a glob pattern or a regexp (see `--path-glob` and `--path-regex`)

Comment: Yes, `git-filter-repo` worked like a charm, took 6s vs 20m for `--index-filter` vs 3h for `--tree-filter`. Thanks for your answer anyway.